# Super button won't open the Dash in an empty workspace

Tags: unity, unity-dash, shortcuts

I was using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome3 for a while, than started back on Unity.

My problem is that the super button only opens the Dash when there are already a few windows in a workspace. When the workspace is empty (there are no windows on that workspace), the only way to open the dash is clicking on the ubuntu icon in the launcher.

Is this the expected behavior or do I have some problem?

---

**SOLUTION**

The problem was caused because I had turned off the Desktop handling by nautilus. So, it seems that this shortcut only runs when there's at least the nautilus Desktop or something else running on that workspace.

It looks like a buggy feature to me. I'll post a bug issue later on when I confirm how to reproduce it, and see what people from the dev team say about it.

Comment: Hi, @TomBrossman and others. I don't want to create a fuss about it, buy I just wanted to ask why do you think the question is off topic. I asked about a problem I had with Ubuntu and its standard stack of softwares (unity, nautilus). I understand that given I'm a newcomer to this SE-site I might have overlooked some rule. Could you please point out what's wrong with the question so that I may avoid this in future questions? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd> (the 'Win' key) opens Dash from empty desktops on my system (12.10) by default.

I can, however, reproduce your situation if I use the *gnome-tweak-tool* to set *Desktop* > *Have file manager handle desktop* to *Off*. Check this setting on your system.

You may have changed something that interacts with this while using Gnome. If it is already set to *On*, set it to *Off* and back to *On* again to force an update through.

Comment: Yes, it was it. I had set off nautilus handling of the desktop. But it's still weird though. It looks like a buggy feature to me. I'll post a bug issue later.